# Who was first to mention the omittance of Gods name from Megilah Esther?

Tags: megillat-esther

Where is the earliest written source that mentions the omittance of Gods name from the Megillah?

Comment: I remember seeing this question on this site very recently, I think it's a dupe. Have a search @TheTargum

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26581/33217

Comment: Possible dupe: "[The earliest source that states the disappearance of the names of God in the Book of Ester](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/125502/1368)" @RabbiKaii